# Proving statement about the ODE $y'=y+y^4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Is there a solution to the problem $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
> y'=y+y^4\\ 
> y(x_0)=y_0
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>   which is defined on $\mathbb{R}$? ($x_0,y_0$ might be any real numbers)

It's easy to prove that for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ there exists an open interval $I$ (with $x_0\in I$) where the problem has a unique solution. However is the maximal interval always $(-\infty,\infty)$? I know that the answer is no, but that's just because I found a solution for particular values of $x_0$ and $y_0$ and checked its domain. But is there a way to prove that $I$ need not be $I=(-\infty,\infty)$ without actually solving the problem for a certain initial condition? In other words, how can I prove that the unique solution need not be defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Three regions: $y > 0$ go to $+\infty$ in finite time. $0 > y > -1$ defined for all $x.$ $y < -1$ come from $-\infty$ in finite time; put another way, run time backwards, these blowup in finite time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actual solutions, three regions: $y > 0,$ then $0 > y > -1,$ then $y < -1.$ I should emphasize that your ODE is autonomous, no explicit dependence on $x,$ which means that every solution curve is a sideways translate of one of those in the picture. It is sort of accidental that a solution for $y > 0$ also provides the exact correct formula for a solution with $y < -1.$ That is why there are two curves in light green, with matching vertical asymptote.

[image]

it is first order, so solutions cannot intersect or cross each other. There are two constant solutions, $y=0$ and $y=-1.$ Between those, solution curves  descend from horizontal asymptote at $y=0$ to that at $y=-1.$

Above $0,$ $y$ increases. Once, say, $y > 2,$ we have $y' > 1 + y^2$ and $y > \tan (x - x_0).$ Blowup in finite time; there is a vertical asymptote.

Similar for $y < -1$ if you run time backwards. Very roughly, the plot of a large number of solution curves can be rotated $180^\circ$ to give something  similar to the original.

Oh, well. You can also change variables to get good estimates on when $y$ goes to $\infty.$ We are free to move right or left, all solution curves are translates of each other. In considering $y > 0,$ we are free to demand $y(0) = 1.$ Next, take
$$ y = \tan w, $$ so $w(0) = \pi/4$ and
$$ y' = \sec^2 w \; w' $$
From $y' = y + y^4, $ I got
$$ w' = \cos w \sin w + \frac{\sin^4 w}{\cos^2 w}.  $$
For $w$ between $\pi/4$ and $\pi/2,$ we know $\sin w \geq 1$ while $\cos w \leq 1.$ So, as a first try, $w' > 1,$ so we know that $w = \pi/2$ occurs with $x < \pi/2 - \pi / 4 = \pi / 4.$ Much greater precision is available, just solve the numerical ODE for $w$ with $w(0) = \pi/4,$ find when $w = \pi/2.$ In fact, since this thing is solvable in closed form, we find $y(0) = 1$ means $y$ goes to infinity, meaning vertical asymptote, at $$ x = \frac{1}{3} \log 2 \approx 0.231049 $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a whole family of solutions of this equation that are defined on the whole real line. Look carefully at the equation itself
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y + y^4$$ and write it in the form
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = y(1 + y^3)$$ As the equation is locally Lipschitz everywhere, because it is polynomial, locally everywhere there exists a unique solution to it and so two solutions cannot cross. Now, observe that the constant functions $y(x) \equiv 0$ and $y(x) \equiv -1$ are actually the unique solutions to the inital value problems
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= y + y^4\\
y(0) &= 0
\end{align} and
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= y + y^4\\
y(0) &= -1
\end{align}
respectively. Since two different solutions of the equations cannot cross unless they coincide everywhere, any solution that satisfies the initial value problem 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} &= y + y^4\\
y(x_0) &= -y_0
\end{align}
for $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R} \times [-1, 0]$ will be trapped in the region $\mathbb{R} \times [-1, 0]$ for all $x$ from their maximal interval of definition and therefore that maximal interval is the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

In conclusion, all solutions $y=y(x)$ of the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x + x^4$$ such that $-1 \leq y(x_0) \leq 0$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ are defined as differentiable functions $y : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that $-1 \leq y(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The question is whether every solution for every initial condition is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bernoulli equation, and can thus be solved directly. Setting $u(x)=y(x)^{-3}+1$ results in the equation
$$
u'(x)=-3y(x)^{-4}y'(x)=-3u(x)\implies u(x)=u(x_0)e^{-3(x-x_0)}
$$
so that
$$
y(x)=\frac{y(0)e^{x-x_0}}{\sqrt[3]{1+y_0^3(1-e^{3(x-x_0)})}}
$$
where the cube root is extended as odd function to negative values.

The solution has a singularity in finite time if the denominator has a root, which is the case if $1+y_0^{-3}>0$, that is, $y_0>0$ or $y_0<-1$.